# How do I require_once() this file?

Tags: php, file, hierarchy

[image]

I want to `require_once()` `dbconnect.php` in `register.php` . How do I do that? I tried `require_once('../dbconnect.php')` but that does not work (though it does work at the `register` level.

Comment: try to diagnose what file it is trying to include by doing `realpath('../dbconnect.php')` in register.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require_once("../../dbconnect.php");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../dbconnect.php';
```

Or if you are using PHP 5.3, replace `dirname(__FILE__)` with `__DIR__`.

If you wanted to be real anal, you could replace `/` with the constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`. :P

Comment: +1 _If you wanted to be real anal, you could replace `/` with the constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`_ :D

Answer (score 1):

Is dbconnect.php inside public_html? if so you will need `require_once('../../dbconnect.php')`

Each ../ represents one directory up. At the moment it's looking in register for dbconnect.php

Answer (score 0):

your code is true, from register folder, you will need to use `require_once(../dbconnect.php)`. well, now we see `require_once()`, "once" is mean it have to included only one time, maybe just check your code. is `require_once(../dbconnect.php)` has been located at this script or other script that included? if you type `require_once(../dbconnect.php)` more than one, this will error.

Answer (score 0):

When u do

```
require_once('../dbconnect.php')
```

.. means the parent directory, so it goes one level up there. Still its there in the register folder. So, to go to its parent directory, you will have to specify one more .. where the file dbconnect.php exists. So you can also use it as
    `require_once __DIR__. '/../dbconnect.php';`